# Laravel handle nested exceptions and keep going

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5, try-catch

I have a question regarding PHP's way to handle exceptions and Laravel 5.
Here's a snippet of what I'm trying to accomplish

```
try
{
//set up webservices
saveData();
} catch(exception $e)
{
Log:error('stuff went bananas')
}

saveData(){
//record stuff through DB with eloquent
//in case some data is missing connect to a second DB
try
{
connect()
query to get data
}catch(exception $e)
{
//log error again
}
```

In other words, I'm calling webservices that receive data. I'm then inserting these into my own DB inside the Model.
At this stage I'm trying to see if I know the user ID that I just received. In case I don't I have to connect to a second database to request that same user.

There are two issues though

- the second database I'm trying to connect isn't likely to be up
- it will often not hold the information I need (I have to try again the next day)

There's nothing I can do against these issues. But what I want is for my code to try and connect, and in case it fails, log the errors and keep moving inserting the data.

Thanks in advance.